# Matrix rank doesn't work as per API specs in parallel colt

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, colt

I am using [parallel colt](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) wherein I need to find the rank of a matrix. The API documentation says the following about the following about [`DoubleAlgebra#rank`](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/algo/DoubleAlgebra.html#rank(cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D)):

> rank(DoubleMatrix2D A)
>
> Returns the effective numerical rank of matrix A, obtained from Singular Value Decomposition.

But when I use it in my code, I get an IllegalArgumentException at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matrix must be dense
    at cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.algo.DoubleProperty.checkDense(Unknown Source)
    at cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.algo.decomposition.DenseDoubleSingularValueDecomposition.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.algo.DenseDoubleAlgebra.svd(Unknown Source)
    at cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.algo.DenseDoubleAlgebra.rank(Unknown Source)
```

The API doesn't mention that a matrix needs to be dense. In my IDE (I use Intellij IDEA), when I ctrl+click the method name in my code, it goes to the source, which shows

```
public int rank(cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D doubleMatrix2D) { /* compiled code */ }
```

Bottomline, everywhere I see the requirement for a `DoubleMatrix2D` object, not a `DenseDoubleMatrix2D` object. Any idea why the runtime exception happens?

Comment: Can you show us something about the matrix you're trying to calculate the rank of? What does it look like? What class instance is it?

Comment: How would you perform [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) with a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, as the message says, it really *does* need a `DenseDoubleMatrix2D` instance.

Here's what the source traces through (simplified with `A` kept the same name throughout):

```
DoubleAlgebra.rank(DoubleMatrix2D A): return svd(A).rank();
  > svd(DoubleMatrix2D A): return new DenseDoubleSingularValueDecomposition(A, true, true);
    > DenseDoubleSingularValueDecomposition(): checkDense(A);
```

For `checkDense` itself:

```
 public void checkDense(DoubleMatrix2D A) {
     if (!(A instanceof DenseDoubleMatrix2D) && !(A instanceof DenseColumnDoubleMatrix2D))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix must be dense");
 }
```

You can see the actual exception code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.parallelcolt/parallelcolt/0.10.0/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/algo/DoubleProperty.java#DoubleProperty.checkDense%28cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D%29).

What you probably want to do is just use an instance of `DenseDoubleMatrix2D` instead of whatever you're currently sending in.

Comment: Yes, that's how I managed to get my code working. In fact, I had ended up at the same grepcode page that you have linked. But, since the API only requires a DoubleMatrix2D argument, shouldn't the source code have `checkDense` return boolean, and the `rank` method have something like `if (checkDense(A) == false) A = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(A.toArray())` ? I guess I am irked more by the undocumented difference between the API and the actual code behavior than anything else.

Comment: It's hard to document every requirement. If my answer helped, I would appreciate the upvote/accept. Your question seemed odd though, something like "why is this documentation wrong?" which is impossible to say, unless you're the author :)